# munin custom plugin with rolling log file

Tags: logging, plugins, munin

I'm creating graphs from rolling log file that is created by log4j. I grep the file for certain keywords and munin creates nice graphs.

The problem occurs when the log file rolls over (max size is 5MB) and a new file is created. Then the values are down to 0 and it looks a little confusing on the graph. What kind of methods would you suggest to make graphs more 'even' ? Thanks.